# Enabling two different chargers with opposite enable line polarity

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb, circuit-design, design

**Premise:**

We have 2 potential chargers:

- https://www.meanwellusa.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=NPP-1700 (*NPP-1700-48*)
- https://www.meanwellusa.com/productPdf.aspx?i=28 (*PB-1000-48*).

The chargers are connected to charging pads, which are basically bare copper pads with a spring and limit switch (NO) internally. A robot comes in and docks on the pads closing the limit switch to commence charging.

The PB-1000-48 only starts charging when it detects a voltage source, the NPP-1700-48 works more like a power supply, once it's turned on it just puts the charge voltage on the output.

Additionally, they both turn on in exactly opposite ways. The NPP charger requires **shorting** 2 pins on its connector, or providing 10.8-13.2V on pin 7 to work:

[image]

Whilst the PB charger expects two pins to be **open** circuit for it to work:

[image]

**Expected Operation**

The way the circuit will work is that once the robot docks and the limit switch(https://docs.rs-online.com/1fc1/0900766b80dd6a18.pdf) (NO) will be pressed and once the robots battery voltage is detected (40-56v), an appropriate signal would be sent to the charger to turn it on.

The battery voltage detection is only required for the NPP charger since the PB manages that on its own.

Finally in the case of the NPP charger, once the two conditions are met (battery voltage and limit switch) a delay (0-5s) adjustable through a pot would be added before charger begins charging. There should be minimal delay at turn off.

I have simulated something in LT spice which does the job but i was hoping if some improvements, suggestions, comments could be added. I am not sure if this has been over complicated.

The SPDT shown here (u4) is simply a 12V relay. So i can use this for the PB charger. I couldn't use a 48V relay directly on the output as it needs to come after the limit switch and the limit switch is rated to 30V.
The mosfet circuit shown is just a buffer circuit (CD4050UB) and i just used the logic block here as shown:
[image]

The buffer was added mainly for the RC delay circuit with R being a 500K POT (R45) here and C (C5) being 10u.
[image]

**NOTE:**

- Both chargers will never be connected across at the same time.
- Once the robot is off the charger, and limit switch released, the charging would stop.

Any help to refine/improve/simplify this circuit and any obvious issues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't leave M20, M21, M24, M25 as default `NMOS` and `PMOS`.  The default models use Vto=0.  Pick something from the built-in list like you did with the others, or go find the actual CD4050 model.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

A single component can do most of it. Just use a relay with a normally closed contact to convert from a normally open condition to a normally closed condition.

For the delay, you may want to just buy an off-the-shelf timer module (cheap, readily available from Amazon and such, easy to configure, guaranteed to work out of the box), rather than spinning your own circuit.

Comment: I do need the delay after the limit switch though. So it wouldn't exactly be a single component. Also the limit switch itself is rated upto 30V and i can't change it. Could you elaborate on your solution?

Comment: When the external battery source is removed the charger would still detect a voltage (the voltage from the charger), this is where the limit switch comes handy too to basically cut the circuit.

Comment: " the charger would still detect  ... the voltage from the charger". Sorry, I don't understand. Why would the charger detect its own voltage?

Comment: As in the charger is on the same line as the battery, once the charger turns on, that voltage would still be there. We would need to look at the limit switch to know that the battery is no longer present and we should cut power to the charger.

Comment: And i suspect the off the shelf timer module would be more expensive.

Comment: "we should cut power to the charger" - Why bother?

Comment: The charger is connected to Live pads (Limit switch is under the live pads). Once the device is not on the live pads anymore (limit switch not pressed) i wouldn't want an exposed voltage to be present there